# Check for line breaks in paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, line-breaks

this is my setup, the solution can be in JS or CSS:

```
<p>
  "Text"
  <br>
  <br>
 "Text2"
  <br>
  <br>
  <br> -> should be hidden
  <br> -> should be hidden
"Text3"

</p>
```

I want to check every paragraph for br, if there are more than 2 br **DIRECTLY** following each other, then I want to hide every br (in that break section) except for the first and second br.

In other words: There is a paragraph. This p contains text, followed by two breaks - thats okay. Then there is more text in the same p, this time followed by 3 breaks. That is not okay, because the 3rd break should be hidden there. There could be more text with breaks following after that.

So in this example only the last two breaks should be hidden. Targeting the childs is not working, because then only the first and second breaks are visible but every break after that is hidden.

Comment: Are you wanting a JavaScript solution, or a CSS solution? You example is using CSS.

Comment: I am happy with both of them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @pwbred Actually I don't think CSS can achieve this goal. Though there is `+` selector, it doesn't take text nodes between elements into consideration.

Comment: @MarvinBlach But `+` *can* work, if you could wrap the text into something like `<span>` respectively.

Comment: @WildernessRanger can you go a bit more into detail how that could work please?

Comment: I also don't think this can be done with pure CSS.

Comment: JS is also okay! :) @technophyle

Comment: Are the ellipsis meaning that can be any text node?

Comment: @JenniferGoncalves That can be just any text.

Comment: it's not easy in JS either, consider this: https://jsfiddle.net/2qwvxe4k/ it lists your sequence correctly because html markup is written all in one line. When code is indented, results are different: https://jsfiddle.net/oa16gwne/

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying to do that for the past 30 minutes lol.. but I think it'd be easier if you can convert those text snippets into an element like spans. Is that in your power or not?

Comment: @technophyle Unfortunately I cant do that.

Comment: If it would have been `<span>Text 2</span>` it should have been something like `br + br + br { display: none; }`

Comment: @MarvinBlach If you wrap each line's text into an element, then you can use a rule like `br + br + br { display: none; }` to hide redundant breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are just going to have BR and text nodes, you can select all the children and loop over them and count the occurrences of the BR tag. If you are over 2, start removing.

```js
// Get all of the nodes in the p element into an array
const nodes = [...document.querySelector("p").childNodes];

// loop over the nodes so we can inspect each one
nodes.reduce((count, node) => {
  // Do we have text node?
  if(node.nodeType === 3) {
    // is the text node just whitespace
    const isEmpty = node.nodeValue.trim().length === 0;

    // if whitespace ignore
    // if text, reset count
    return isEmpty ? count : 0; 
  }
  // update the count for number of brs encountered
  count++;
  // if we are at number 3 or greater remove it
  if (count>2) node.remove();
  // return the count
  return count;
}, 0);
```

```html
<p>
  "Text"
  <br>
  <br> 
  "Text2"
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  "Text3"
</p>
```

And if you have more than one you have to select all the paragraphs and loop over that and process each one.

```js
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");

paragraphs.forEach( elem => {
  const nodes = [...elem.childNodes];
  nodes.reduce((count, node) => {
    if(node.nodeType === 3) {
      const isEmpty = node.nodeValue.trim().length === 0;
      return isEmpty ? count : 0; 
    }
    count++;
    if (count>2) node.remove();
    return count;
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<p>
  "Text"
  <br>
  <br> 
  "Text2"
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  "Text3"
</p>
<p>
  "Text"
  <br>
  <br> 
  <br>
  <br> 
  <br>
  <br> 
  "Text2"
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  "Text3"
</p>
```

Comment: This is the error I am getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'childNodes') :/

Comment: You are either reading element before it exists or your selector is wrong.

Comment: I am struggling to make this run only on mobile devices. Can you help me out @epascarello? I tried the following: if( screen.width <= 480 ) {      
 
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");

paragraphs.forEach( elem => {
  const nodes = [...elem.childNodes];
  nodes.reduce((count, node) => {
    if(node.nodeType === 3) {
      const isEmpty = node.nodeValue.trim().length === 0;
      return isEmpty ? count : 0; 
    }
    count++;
    if (count>2) node.remove();
    return count;
  }, 0);
});

}

Answer (score 1):

Let's try with regexp. I was thinking along the line of `/<br>\s*<br>\s*((<br>\s*)*)/`

Then I looked up for negative lookbehind something. It seems to be working.

```js
var str = `
<p>
  "...."
  <br>
  <br>
 "...."
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</p>`;


var reg = /(?<=<br>\s*<br>\s*)((<br>\s*)+)/gm;

console.log(str.replace(reg, ''));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

Comment: And then there's this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3930247

Comment: But I agree, this would probably be the best answer.

Comment: Technically yes. This solution only supports `<br>` tags exactly written like that. Another possibility is using DOM or DOMParser to parse the nodes of the element and manipulate that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do I make it work for EVERY paragraph, not just this example? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your text nodes in a span, using the standard [find-text-nodes trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery), then use `.nextUntil` to hide the extra nodes:

```
$("span + br + br").nextUntil("span").hide();
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$("p")
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.textContent.trim() != ""; //Node.TEXT_NODE
  }).wrap("<span>");
  
$("span + br + br").nextUntil("span").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  "Text"
  <br>
  <br>
 "Text2"
  <br>
  <br>
  <br> 
  <br>
  "Text3"
  <br>
  <br>
  <br> 
  <br>
  "Text3"
  <br>
  <br>
  <br> 
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br> 
  <br>
  "Text3"
</p>
```

---

If you don't want to use `.nextUntil` but are still ok with wrapping the text in a `span` (or can change the HTML to wrap the text in a span), then you can also use css:

Hide all `<br>`, then show the ones you want `span + br, span + br + br`

Updated snippet:

```js
$("p")
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.textContent.trim() != ""; //Node.TEXT_NODE
  }).wrap("<span>");
```

```css
span { color: red; } /* just to show they've been wrapped in a span */

br { display:none; }
p > span + br,
p > span + br + br { display:inline; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  "Text"
  <br>
  <br>
 "Text2"
  <br>
  <br>
  <br> 
  <br>
  "Text3"
  <br>
  <br>
  <br> 
  <br>
  "Text3"
  <br>
  <br>
  <br> 
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br> 
  <br>
  "Text3"
  

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using RegEx for processing HTML is generally not recommended but in this case, I think it's the only answer.

According to [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73805472/3930247) and using JS:

```js
const regex = /(?<=<br>\s*<br>\s*)((<br>\s*)*)/gm;
const paragraph = document.querySelector('p')
paragraph.innerHTML = paragraph.innerHTML.replace(regex, '')
```

```html
<p>
  Hi!
  <br>
  <br>
  Welcome to StackOverflow!
  <br>
  Thanks!
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  Bye!
</p>
```

If wrapping up the text elements in `span` tags is possible, as epascarello commented, we can simply do this:

```css
p>br+br+br {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Hi!</span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span>Welcome to StackOverflow!</span>
  <br>
  <span>Thanks!</span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span>Bye!</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error message here: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'regex' has already been declared. Do you know what I can do about that, but your solution is exactly what I need.

Comment: Maybe just change the name to something else "regEx" for example.

Comment: When I do that I am getting this error here, that is pretty strange: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: Do you know where that error happens?

Comment: I just pasted it in the console.

Comment: You can't paste the HTML code in the console and expect it to work. HTML is not JavaScript.

Comment: I mean, did you just paste the JS?

Comment: First I had it in the body, but that didnt work either :/ I put it into script tags.

Comment: If your code has no other syntax error, and you put the three lines of code into a script tag (whether it's head or body), I'm pretty sure it'll work.